# Queue that stores User's entered Array and displays it

Tags: c#, arrays, queue

So i have a simple program that i have set up to ask the user for an array size then it gets them to enter the elements then prints them, i would like to set up a Queue so it prints a whole of the array, for example.

History

### 1 2 3 4 //Length of the Array

3 4 5 6 //User Guess for this round

After this every time the user re enters the array that array would show up in the history also.

History

### 1 2 3 4 //Length of the Array

3 4 5 6 //User Guess for this round
2 6 7 8 //User second input

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

  namespace Random_test
 {
   class Program
  {
    public int n;
    public int[] UserArray;
    public int i;
    public int reEnter;
    public int rear = -1;
    public int front = -1;
    public int[] history;

    public void main()
    {


        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Length of Your array");

        n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        UserArray = new int[n];
        history = new int[n];

        do
        {

            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your Elements");

                UserArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            }

            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your Array: {0} ", UserArray[i]);

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to re-enter your array");
            reEnter = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)//loop for history
            {
                insert();
                delete();
                showHistory();
            }

        } while (reEnter == 1);


    }


    public void insert()
    {


        if (rear == -1)
        {
            front = 0;
            rear++;

            history[rear] = UserArray[i];

        }
        else
        {
            rear++;
            history[rear] = UserArray[i];
        }
    }

    public void delete()
    {
        if (front == -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There is no history availible");
        }
        else
        {
            front++;
        }

    }

    public void showHistory()
    {
        if (rear == -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There is no history availible");

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("History");

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(" {0} ");
                Console.Write(" - ");
                Console.WriteLine(" {0} ", history[i]);
            }

        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program main = new Program();
        main.main();


        Console.WriteLine("Game Over");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

---

This was just a quick jot up program as you can see i have attempted to do the Queue, it works but prints only the first element of the User Array each turn. Unfortunately this is where i do not know how implement what i talked about at the start of the post. I would like to stick to this method of creating the Queues, i do not want to use the queue class, the idea is to keep it clean and simple.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to break it to you, but there's nothing clean nor simple here :/

Comment: @MikkoViitala What would be my best option, when i said Clean and simple i meant, using no special C# Operators or Methods.

Comment: Best option would be to rethink and redo, there's just too much to fit in one comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my evil comments before. I think this might suite your level... happy coding.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        (new Program()).Ask();
    }

    private void Ask()
    {
        string history = "";

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Len > ");
            int len = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int[] arr = new int[len];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("El{0} > ", i);
                arr[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            string str = string.Join(",", arr);
            Console.WriteLine("Arr > {0}", str);

            Console.WriteLine("His > {0}", history);
            history += string.Format("[{0}] ", str);

            Console.WriteLine("Again?");
            if (Console.ReadLine().Length == 0)
                break;
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's alright, thank you I'll have a go at this tomorrow. Have been trying to get this to work for a couple of days. But its just a learning process I guess.

Comment: Yes this what i needed for display purposes, but idea is that it stores the history each time so the history builds up. that is were i am  stuck.

Comment: I Suppose i have one last question is there a way of doing this without using .join and .format, as i would rather know how it is working than using special c# methods.

Comment: Of course you can do things in many ways. But these are not "special" but very basic methods. With join you can e.g. get a human readable format out of an array and with Format you define how you want stuff to be formatted. If you use only arrays it's more complicated and error prone, not to mention less readable.